# jquery change background color of h4 on click

Tags: jquery

Right now after click my div .box is changing the background colour to blue, I would like that apply for the children h4 so the blue background will be just in the children h4 of the div box.

div box none background when is clicked and 
h4 will get blue background

html:

```
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4>
  </h4>
</div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var click = false;
  $(document).on('click', '.box', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      click = false;
      return false;
    }
    if (!click) {
      $(this).find("i").removeClass('red');
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
      click = true;
    } else {
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass('red');
    }
  });
});
```

css:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.highlight {
  background: #0000FF;
}

.fa-trash.red {
  color: red;
}

.fa-trash {
  color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wv4f2hda/7/

Comment: use `$(this).find('h4').addClass('highlight');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$(this).addClass('highlight');` with `$("h4", this).addClass('highlight');`

Comment: you had forgot it in the second if block

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var click = false;
  $(document).on('click', '.box', function() {
    if ($(this).find('h4').hasClass('highlight')) {
      $(this).find('h4').removeClass('highlight');
      click = false;
      return false;
    }
    if (!click) {
      $(this).find("i").removeClass('red');
      $(this).find('h4').addClass('highlight');
      click = true;
    } else {
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass('red');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but what happen if the h4 has background colour before? .box h4 {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 7px;
}  https://jsfiddle.net/wv4f2hda/9/

Comment: Simply you can add `!important` to your `.highlight` CSS class, Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv4f2hda/10/) :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to do this, either directly select the `h4` inside your `div` box like `$('.box > h4')`, or by using `find()` function like `$('.box').find('h4')`.

Example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var click = false;
  $('.box > h4').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      click = false;
      return false;
    }
    if (!click) {
      $(this).find("i").removeClass('red');
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
      click = true;
    } else {
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass('red');
    }
  });


  /* You can also do this */
  /*
  $('.box').find('h4').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      click = false;
      return false;
    }
    if (!click) {
      $(this).find("i").removeClass('red');
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
      click = true;
    } else {
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass('red');
    }
  });
  */
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.highlight {
  background: #0000FF;
}
.fa-trash.red {
  color: red;
}
.fa-trash {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4>
  </h4>
</div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4>
</div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4>
</div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i>
  <h4>
hello world </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but what happen if the h4 has background colour before? .box h4 { font-size: 0.875rem; background-color: #eeeeee; padding: 7px; } jsfiddle.net/wv4f2hda/9

Comment: The simplest thing you could do is add !important to the background attribute in .highlight class. Something like this .highlight {
  background: #0000FF !important;
}